# Divergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a \cos(b \ln n)+b \sin(b \ln n)}{n^a}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, summation, riemann-zeta

> Divergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a \cos(b \ln n) + b\sin(b \ln n)}{n^a}$$ where $0<a<1, b>0$ are constants.

**My try:**
$$\cos(x)\geq 1-\frac{x^2}{2} , \forall x$$
$$\sin (x)\geq -x , \ \forall x$$
$$a\cos(b \ln n)+b\sin(b \ln n)\geq a\left(1-\frac{(b\ln \ n)^2}{2}\right)-b^2 \ln\  n$$

How to bound the given summation?

Comment: @gt6989b Any hints for the question?

Comment: @Mathlover Please answer the question.

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: @metamorphy Actually the riemann-zeta tag is a bit weird

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let's try something simpler: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos(\ln n)}{n^a}.$ For each positive integer $m,$ let $E_m$ be the set of integers $n$ such that

$$2\pi m <\ln n < \pi/3+2\pi m.$$

Then

$$\sum_{n\in E_m}\frac{\cos(\ln n)}{n^a} > |E_m|\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{(e^{\pi/3+2\pi m})^a}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what for cos(b ln n)? Also in the last step, the summation is in $A_m$? What is $A_m$?

Comment: Also what about sin(b ln n) term?

Comment: I will give you a check mark. Please answer my doubts.

Comment: That should have been $E_m.$ If you can solve the simpler problem I discussed, you should be able to answer the original question.

Comment: So the series is divergent?

Comment: @zwh. How to conclude from the last step. How to get summation 1 to $\infty$ from $E_m$?

Comment: When I have a little time I'll give more details.